# HTML: references tags <!--% What is it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic

So I need to modify few things in HTML that has weird reference tags to js elements/objects. I googled the hell out of it and I cannot find anything useful as not sure what to search for.

Code looks like this:

```
    <div class="test-item">
        <h4><!--% obj.translate_this('Incomplete').dquote() | html %--> (<!--% c.test.incomplete.size OR 0 %-->)</h4>
        <!--% FOREACH lang = c.test.incomplete %-->
            <!--% c.languages.$lang %--><br />
        <!--% END %-->
    </div>
```

So the questions is: **`<!--% FOREACH lang = c.test.incomplete %-->`** what language is it?
Would you be able to point me to some documentation so I could read more about it? For example, syntax, methods, how to use and sort FOREACH.

Many thanks

Comment: All of my Google searches seem to suggest that this is PERL templates, although the syntax you've provided differs slightly.  Have a look [here](http://template-toolkit.org/about.html).

Comment: Seems to me as usage of a framework (e.g. Django) which are commented out as they not implemented yet and as such should not be rendered.

Comment: **Robert** - we do use perl but yes, that syntax differs and unfortunately I cannot find anything similar.

**tacoshy** - at first I thought the same however **%** added to line renders it properly. So it doesn't look like its commented.

Comment: Do you have _just_ the HTML? If not, then I'd start by looking around the rest of the project, which templating library/-ies might get used.

Comment: Reviving old thread. Found an article which helped me get what I wanted. Had to swap opening/closing brackets but the syntax was pretyy much the same

http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_IF_UNLESS_ELSIF_ELSE

hope that helps